# How to extract table data in node js which are in the form of xml?

Tags: node.js

```
<partial-response id="j_id1"><changes><update id="convVeh_Form:j_idt15"><![CDATA[<div id="convVeh_Form:j_idt15" class="ui-messages ui-widget" aria-live="polite"></div>]]></update><update id="convVeh_Form:rcPanel"><![CDATA[<div id="convVeh_Form:rcPanel" class="ui-outputpanel ui-widget"><div id="convVeh_Form:j_idt24" class="ui-outputpanel ui-widget">
                            <div class="center-position bottom-space">
                                <span class="font-bold text-underline">Vehicle Details Showing in Registering Authority</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="font-bold top-space bottom-space text-capitalize"> 
                                Registering Authority  raygada, odisha
                            </div>
                            <table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-condensed table-bordered data-table">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span class="font-bold">Registration No:</span></td>
                                    <td>OR02AA1111</td>
                                    <td><span class="font-bold">Registration Date:</span></td>
                                    <td>17-Oct-2003</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span class="font-bold">Chasi No:</span></td>
                                    <td>LF501090981</td>
                                    <td><span class="font-bold">Engine No:</span></td>
                                    <td>2L9813780</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span class="font-bold">Owner Name:</span> </td>
                                    <td colspan="3">ASHOK KUMAR SAHU</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span class="font-bold">Vehicle Class:</span> </td>
                                    <td>L.M.V.(JEEP/GYPSY - P)</td>
                                    <td><span class="font-bold">Fuel Type:</span></td>
                                    <td>DIESEL</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span class="font-bold">Maker Model:</span></td>
                                    <td colspan="3">TOYOTA KIRLOSKAR MOTORS LTD, QUALIS</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table></div></div>]]></update><update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"><![CDATA[-6252284414753420545:-5710569301313650409]]></update></changes></partial-response>
```

*I need to extract rows of table eg- OR02AA1111 and so on.* 
I have tried it converting to json format but failed to parse in node js.

Is there any way i can extarct data by passing key value pair like we do for json

Comment: @Biswamatma - I wasn't aware that the output you had was in XML, thought it was just pure HTML. Ok my bad, that solution I had obviously won't work on XML. You might want to look around the NPM area for a XML2Json parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var xpath = require('xpath')
                , dom = require('xmldom').DOMParser


            var doc = new dom().parseFromString(body)
            var nodes = xpath.select("//update[2]", doc)

            var doc1 = new dom().parseFromString(nodes[0].firstChild.data)
            var RegistraionNumber = xpath.select("//table/tr[1]/td[2]/text()", doc1)
```

Finally I have done this using xpath .